# iChat Download For OS X 10.6.8

Tags: mac, ichat

I foolishly deleted iChat Application from my Mac with version of 10.6.8 for free disk space. Now am trying to download the .dmg file for the iChat app. Can anyone help me in this by sending any link to download the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is reported on [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1486891?threadID=1486891) on the Apple Support Communities.

They report several ways to do that.
The easiest way seems to be:

> Insert your Tiger/Leopard/Snow Leopard DVD into your drive. Once the
>   DVD loads, open the "Optional Installs" folder and then the .mpkg of
>   the same name. This will launch an Installer. Click through until you
>   get the option of choosing what you'd like to install. (this is after
>   the Licence Agreement part)
>
> Open the "Applications" by using the tick box and triangle for the
>   drop down menu in the panel of software to install, simply choose
>   iChat (only) and let the installer do the work.

Comment: Yup. i tried but when i am trying to download,am not getting installation process.
unknowingly it is closing.
can u tell me why it is...?
and thanks for the reply.

Comment: "iChat Update (PowerPC) can’t be installed on this computer." this is am getting.

Comment: version 10.6.8 Processor 2.4 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo Memory 2 Gb 800 Mhz. Is it Sufficient..?

Comment: i tried that one also but it is taking almost 118 GB Hard Disk Space..:(

Comment: sorry am mistaken, my harddisk space is 117 GB and it takes 11.5 mb space. Even am not able to install it,

Comment: iChat Update (Universal) can't be installed on this disk.This volume does not meet the requirements for this update..

Comment: Nope............:((